# dnsmasq only working on local machine

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and I installed dnsmarq.

The contents of my dnsmasq.conf is

```
address=/project.dev/192.168.0.2

listen-address=127.0.0.1 
listen-address=192.168.0.2
bind-interfaces
```

From my local machine I'm able to reach project.dev, however, from another device on the same local network this is not possible.
The device can reach the local machine (with dnsmasq) using the static IP (192.168.0.2), and the DNS IP of the device is set to static IP of the local machine (192.168.0.2).
Is there something missing in the config files that doesn't allow me to reach the DNS server or that prevents the DNS server from giving the wrong IP for project.dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not working due to the fact that the browser on my device (Safari on iPhone 4s) turns the URL 'project.dev' into a search query and hence tries to contact google. Changing my URL to, for example, 'project.com' solves the issue.